# обработка большого числа кнопок в android

Tags: java, android, button, коллекции

Добрый день!
Возникла необходимость обработки двенадцати кнопок в одном фрагменте (калькулятор). Для удобства хотелось бы хранить все эти кнопки в коллекции.

```
    buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    buttons.add(0, (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_0));
    buttons.add(1, (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_1));
    buttons.add(2, (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_2));
    buttons.add(3, (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_3));
    buttons.add(4, (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_4));
    buttons.add(5, (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_5));
    buttons.add(6, (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_6));
    buttons.add(7, (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_7));
    buttons.add(8, (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_8));
    buttons.add(9, (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_9));
```

и т.д.
Можно ли как-то сделать это в цикле? 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: добавить можно, но вам втогда все равно нужно иметь список их айдишников R.id.button...

Comment: Вы можете программно создавать и добавлять кнопки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, вам необходимо сделать так:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("button_".concat(String.valueOf(i)), "id", getActivity().getPackageName());
    buttons.add((Button) view.findViewById(id));
}
```